# Copy current location to clipboard

Tags: powershell

How do I copy the current working directory to clipboard?

```
PS C:\jacek> pwd | CLIP
```

I get content like below. How can I copy only location/value without any whitespace or description?

```
Path
--
C:\jacek
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Update your code to just return the `Path`:

```
(pwd).Path | CLIP
```

---

If you're using PowerShell v5 or newer you can use [Set-Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard) instead of clip(.exe).

```
(pwd).Path | Set-Clipboard
```

Comment: Sometimes I forget just how powerful the pipe | command can be

Comment: and just to save an extra character typing effort `$pwd.path | clip` . it is how powershell variables are called.

Answer (score 14):

In PowerShell 5.0 and above, you can also use

```
(pwd).Path | scb
```

or

```
scb (pwd).Path
```

where scb is an alias for `Set-Clipboard`

Documentation available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.1